# Replacing ABS Drain Pipe Cleanout

Tags: plumbing, repair, leak, pipe

A PVC drain pipe in my basement boiler room is leaking at the cleanout fitting. I have been unable to locate the leak visually. I tried unscrewing the plug, cleaning it, putting on fresh silicone, and putting it back. This, unfortunately, did not stop the leaking.

I have bought a new replacement section for the spout, but all online guides I see seem to say to remove and replace the entire bottom section of ABS pipe (the pipe extending below this spout joint). This pipe goes down into concrete, as pictured below, so I wanted to avoid removing it, if possible.

How can I safely replace this spout joint, preferably without having to remove any concrete?

[image: Picture of Leaking spout]

Comment: That's a "cleanout", not a spout. Also, silicone is not a plumbing product.

Comment: You've asked an [XY question](http://xyquestion.info), about your proposed solution instead of the problem. I suggest revising to do the latter instead.

Comment: That is ABS not PVC.  It most likely has a crack. look for a crack near the bottom of the threaded cap. and the threaded part of the fitting.

Answer (score 2):

The leak we see there probably does not call for replacement of major fittings unless it was abused by overtightening. The plug threads should normally be sealed with PTFE (Teflon) tape or thread compound paste, not caulk.

In this case I suggest that you remove the plug, clean it and teh female threads thoroughly with a nylon brush and rags, and reinstall it with proper plumbing thread compound. At this point, with caulk residue all over it, I wouldn't trust thread tape as much as paste.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot stop the leak per @isherwood, you likely have a crack in the fitting as per @RMDman.  You have two options:

Option 1 - replace the fitting.  remove the cracked fitting by cutting the pipe above and below it and replace it.  You will also need one coupling and a short piece of pipe to make up for what was lost.

Option 2 - patch the leak, for example, [ABS patch](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how%20to%20replace%20a%20leaking%20abs%20drain%20fitting%3F&atb=v296-1&iax=videos&ia=videos&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DBDUfM39r7PY) shows one way in detail.  This is not to code, please note.  I would do it before breaking up concrete if it were my house.  Your call.